# RxJs: How can I simplify this observable chain?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an observable chain that creates inner observables based on conditions. See the inner `switchMap` in the following example:

```
this.init().pipe(
  switchMap(() => {
    return this.structureService.get(...).pipe(
      switchMap((structure) => {
        // update structure if it has changes
        if (structure.changed) {
          return this.structureService.update(...);
        }

        // don't do anything if there are no changes
        return of({}); // I don't like this
      })
    );
  }),
  tap(()=> {
    console.log('done');
  })
);
```

I don't like to return `of({});` because it's not what actually happens but solely serves the purpose of emitting when nothing has to be updated.
Maybe this is doable with `mergeMap` - I tried but couldn't wrap my head around it.

Comment: maybe `return EMPTY` ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not fully equivalent, because it might depend on what's happening in each `switchMap`, but in general you can flatten them out, and with `filter` you will avoid the `of({})`:

```
this.init().pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.structureService.get(...))
  filter(structure => structure.changed),
  switchMap(() => this.structureService.update(...)),
  tap(()=> {
    console.log('done');
  })
);
```

Comment: Nice approach! The problem with this is that the `tap` won't be reached if the structure has not updated (which I need).

Comment: Perhaps a `finalize()` solves your problem?

Comment: depending on your needs either with `finalize` or with `tap({complete: () => {}})` you should be able to overcome the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you prefer a minified code?

```
this.init().pipe(
      switchMap(() => this.structureService.get(...).pipe(
          switchMap((structure) => 
            structure.changed ? this.structureService.update(...) : of({})
          )
        )
      ),
      tap(()=> {
        console.log('done');
      })
    );
```

Comment: My issue is with using `of({})` and not the line count nor formatting of my code.